# Iterate through folders, read JSON, and combine

Tags: r, json, loops, jsonlite

I have a large number of directories with one JSON file in each of them. I'm trying to iterate through these folders, read each JSON file, combine them into a single data frame. Each directory has unique name, but inside is JSON file with identical name.

I set working directory as the one that has these directories I want to iterate. The code below works fine when reading single JSON file, but I can't seem to successfully construct a for loop.

```
setwd("'directory path'")
json_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON("./politifact11773/news content.json", flatten = T)
```

This line works without any error. `jsonlite::read_json` or `jsonlite::fromJSON(readLines("./politifact11773/news content.json"))` works as the same.

Now, when I try getting the list of directory names, construct path strings and iterate through them, I run into errors.

```
dir_list <- list.dirs(recursive = F)
path <- paste0(dir_list, "/news content.json")
vec_list <- list()

for (i in 1:length(path)) {
  json_data <- jsonlite::fromJSON(path[i], flatten = TRUE)
  vec_list[i] <- c("url" = json_data$url,
                   "title" = json_data$title,
                   "text" = json_data$text,
                   "top_img" = json_data$top_img,
                   "type" = json_data$meta_data$og$type,
                   "site_name" = json_data$meta_data$og$site_name,
                   "section" = json_data$meta_data$article$section,
                   "publish_date" = lubridate::as_datetime(json_data$publish_date))
}
return(vec_list)
```

My plan is to row bind the resulting list into a data frame. When I run the for loop I get the following error

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       ./politifact13541/news content.
                     (right here) ------^
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
3: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
4: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
5: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
6: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
7: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
8: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
9: In vec_list[i] <- c(url = json_data$url, title = json_data$title,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Been Googling around and trying different things, but can't seem to find a breakthrough!

Your help will be much appreciated!

I'm attaching a sample [JSON file](https://utexas.box.com/s/px0t6240lk2acft74iidmvsqtxyeuao9) for your reference. Since I'm not super familiar with JSON yet, I wanted to also check whether it is because something with JSON format itself.

Thanks.

Comment: For programmatic use of `jsonlite`, I suggest you replace the use of `fromJSON` with either `read_json` (from a file or URL) or `parse_json` (from a string). I suspect the reason your stuff is failing is that `fromJSON` tries to look for a file and, if not found, treats it like a json string and tries to decode it. I suspect if you just replace with `read_json`, it will say something like "No such file or directory" (which, if true, is a much better error message).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for such a prompt reply! I was able to get it run successfully using both `full.names = T` option and `read_json`. Also found few folders were empty. Constructed another short for loop to get rid of those and the code worked just fine! Thanks! :)

Comment: You may prefer something like "`list.files(path=".", pattern="^news content\\.json$", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)` to look for the literal filename in any of the subdirectories (recursively). The disadvantage with this is that it dives more than 1 directory deep; in which case you can reduce it to `list.files(list.dirs(".", recursive=FALSE), pattern="^news content.json$", recursive=FALSE, full.names=TRUE)`. Both of these will prevent file-not-found.